# BackboneJS Youtube Player not firing video

Tags: backbone.js, youtube, youtube-api

I have this Backbone App where I want display videos from youtube in a view. I fetch the youtube video id dynamically through an API and a Model. So far so good. The Youtube Player gets rendered, but the Player gives me an error which indicates that it didnt recognize the VideoID even though when I console.log the video_id, it returns the correct video_id.

So my View looks like this:

```
beforeRender: function() {
    var artistvideosModel = new ArtistVideos.ArtistVideosModel();
    artistvideosModel.artist_id = this.artist_id;
    artistvideosModel.video_youtube_id = this.video_youtube_id;
    artistvideosModel.fetch();
},

afterRender: function() {

  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    player = new YT.Player('vid', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: this.video_youtube_id,
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue here? Please help...

Thanks in advance

Comment: `this` in the context of your `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function does not refer to your view.

Comment: @kalley strange, when I do `console.log(this.video_youtube_id)` - it returns the correct Video ID...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the context:

```
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = _.bind(function() {
  player = new YT.Player('vid', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: this.video_youtube_id,
    events: {
      onReady: onPlayerReady,
      onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
    }
 })
}, this);
```

Comment: Somehow, it only gets triggered once!? When I close it and try to open the video I get blank page!??